# Missing Vulkan DXVK dependencies of programs

Tags: updates, 18.10, 32-bit, vulkan

So I removed an invalid 1386 file structure. When doing I had no access to the folder then had to delete it and contents to remove the invalid file structure.  This is needed for programs that run with launchers and lutris itself is not required to have but recommended for many of its programs.

What I'd like to finish install 1386 and vulkan.

When I attempted to install them I am told that the file structure is not found if installing DXVK.

```
$ sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libvulkan1:i386
```

How would I tell the system I am adding a file structure i386 and then install the dependencies for other programs using the DXVK libraries.

Thank you in advance. Any advice is appreciated.